# Problem in writing to CSV file from Python in Mac

Tags: python, excel, macos, csv

I read some new data from the MySQL database and then process them. The output will be written in a CSV file. The problem is CSV file does not show contents correctly. The following is content of one of cells:

```
 11- ÿ∑ÿ±ÿßÿ≠€åÿå ÿ≥ÿßÿÆÿ™ Ÿà Ÿæ€åÿßÿØŸáÿ≥ÿßÿ≤€å ÿ≥€åÿ≥ÿ™ŸÖŸáÿß€å ŸáŸàÿ¥ŸÖŸÜÿØ ÿßÿ™ŸàŸÖÿßÿ≥€åŸàŸÜ
```

I expect to see: (When I print in console it shows them correctly)

```
11- طراحی، ساخت و پیادهسازی سیستمهای هوشمند اتوماسیون
```

The code I'm using to write the CSV file is:

```
with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile: 
    # creating a csv writer object 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 
        
    # writing the fields 
    csvwriter.writerow(fields) 
        
    # writing the data rows 
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

I'm using Mac with Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Which version of Excel?  Some version of Excel on the Mac don't understand UTF-8 unless you tell it to.  See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-for-mac-not-opening-utf-8-csv-files/67d951d3-b616-4f7d-9d9a-af76045f7947

Comment: try opening the csv as a text file, in VSCode, or whichever other text editing software you have. What does it show?